# What's the function of log2 in bit-manipulation?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

Why do we use log2 to get the position of the rightmost set bit?
I can't understand. The entire code is here. Thanks a lot!

```
unsigned int getFirstSetBitPos(int n) 
{ 
    return log2(n & -n) + 1; 
}
```

Comment: You don't.  You use `n & -n` to clear all except the rightmost set bit.  Then `log2` on a value with only one bit set (at most)

Comment: Why not use [ffs()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ffs) or the Windows equivalent?

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And keep the title as a short *summary* of your question, and put the actual question inside the question body. And please elaborate on *what* you don't understand, what you *do* understand.

Comment: @Shawn AFAIK, there is no equivalent on Windows.

Comment: @RemyLebeau there is, it's `_BitScanForward`

Comment: @harold That is a compiler-specific function. In this case, specific to MSVC, which is not the only compiler for Windows.

Comment: @RemyLebeau  irrelevant pedantry, ignoring niche compilers in a comment is better than pretending there is no such function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Binary logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_logarithm) on Wikipedia:

> In mathematics, the binary logarithm (log<sub>*2*</sub>  *n*) is the power to which the number 2 must be raised to obtain the value *n*. That is, for any real number *x*,
>
> *x* = log<sub>*2*</sub> ⁡*n* ⟺ 2<sup>*x*</sup> = *n*.
>
> For example, the binary logarithm of 1 is 0, the binary logarithm of 2 is 1, the binary logarithm of 4 is 2, and the binary logarithm of 32 is 5.

So, in your code, `n & -n` first turns off all bits *other than* the rightmost bit that was originally set to 1, then it takes the log<sub>2</sub> of that resulting number to get its power-of-2 (which happens to be the same value as the 0-based position of the bit that was set to 1), and finally adds 1 to that result to get a 1-based bit position (which is weird since bits are typically referred to by their 0-based positions instead).

For example, let's look at `5`.  In binary, 5 is bits `00000000000000000000000000000101` (assuming a 32bit `int` type), and `-5` is bits `11111111111111111111111111111011` (assuming negative integers are implemented using [2s-complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)).  Remember that the `&` operator performs a [bitwise `AND`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) operation, which returns a `1` for a given bit only if that bit is `1` in *both* input numbers, otherwise it returns a `0` instead. Thus:

```
  00000000000000000000000000000101 (5)
& 11111111111111111111111111111011 (-5)
----------------------------------
  00000000000000000000000000000001 (1)
```

So, `5 & -5 = 1`, then `log2(1) = 0`, and `0 + 1 = 1`.

Let's take a look at a more complex number, `1041204192`, which is bits `00111110000011111000001111100000`, and `-1041204192` is bits `11000001111100000111110000100000`:

```
  00111110000011111000001111100000 (1041204192)
& 11000001111100000111110000100000 (-1041204192)
----------------------------------
  00000000000000000000000000100000 (32)
```

So `1041204192 & -1041204192 = 32`, then `log2(32) = 5`, and `5 + 1 = 6`.

Just for kicks, lets look at `0`:

```
  00000000000000000000000000000000 (0)
& 00000000000000000000000000000000 (-0)
----------------------------------
  00000000000000000000000000000000 (0)
```

So `0 & -0 = 0`, and `log2(0)` is `-INFINITY` which is **undefined** for integers.

Here is `-1`:

```
  11111111111111111111111111111111 (-1)
& 00000000000000000000000000000001 (--1)
----------------------------------
  00000000000000000000000000000001 (1)
```

So `(-1) & -(-1) = 1`, then `log2(1) = 0`, and `0 + 1 = 1`.

And `-2`:

```
  11111111111111111111111111111110 (-2)
& 00000000000000000000000000000010 (--2)
----------------------------------
  00000000000000000000000000000010 (2)
```

So `(-2) & -(-2) = 2`, then `log2(2) = 1`, and `1 + 1 = 2`.

And so on...